# Understanding bootstrap carousel code

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Hey guys I am new to JS and jQuery in general and I was just going through the source of carousel.js and came across the following line of code:

```
this.cycle(true)
```

Now the cycle function looks something like this:

```
  Carousel.prototype.cycle = function (e) {

    // console.log('inside cycle');
    e || (this.paused = false)

    this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)

    this.options.interval
      && !this.paused
      && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval))

    return this
  }
```

If I `console.log(e)`, I never get 'true' **WHY?** 
The line I am referring to can be found [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js#L99').

Can somebody explain to me why is `this.cycle()` being passed the value `true` on that line?

Thank you.

Comment: That's another reason to not write your code in a terrible way like `e || (this.paused = false)`

Answer (score 3):

console.log(e) inside the cycle function should return true. But the breakdown of the code that makes it easier to understand is this:

```
Carousel.prototype.cycle = function (e) {

    // console.log('inside cycle');
    //e || (this.paused = false)
    if(!e){
        this.paused=false;
    }

    //this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)
    if(this.interval){
        clearInterval(this.interval);   
    }

    /*
    this.options.interval
      && !this.paused
      && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval))
    */
    if(this.options.interval && !this.paused){
        this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval)
    }
    return this
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code if you don't pass anything or pass `false` it will also unpause the carousel. Passing `true` basically means "do not scroll my carousel automatically". This code does the magic:

```
this.paused = false
```